# session.get_expiry_age() never decreases

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-sessions, django-cookies

I set `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` to some value in my `settings.py` and I want to retrieve the time that is left before a session dies by using `session.get_expiry_age()` from a view.

However, it seems the returned value is never changing between different calls (at different times): it stays at `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`, meaning the session will never end(?)

Is it a normal behaviour? I would like to notify the user whenever the session is about expire and I don't really see how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the intended behaviour. See this ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18458

You can use `get_expiry_date()` instead and calculate it from there.

Comment: Are you sure about `get_expiry_date()`? My tests show the date returned always increases when I call it, such that the time until it expires never decreases, in the same way that `get_expiry_age` never decreases.

Comment: How are you testing it? I assume that something is causing the cookie to be re-set (logging in, middleware, etc.).

Comment: Set a `breakpoint()` in the view. set the cookie, then print `request.session['...'].get_expiry_date()`, then print it again. There is nothing happening inbetween the prints as its in breakpoint mode. How are you testing it?

Comment: Looking at the code, which may have changed in the six years since I answered this: you are right, in that the expiry age will usually change as time goes on. But there are some cases where it will return the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` value. It's a bit hard to intuit from the code what these cases are. One such case is where the setting is `0` or `None`, but that's not the case for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find the way to get **how much session expiry time is left**.

Then, I tested [**get_expiry_age()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_age), [**get_session_cookie_age()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_session_cookie_age) and [**get_expiry_date()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_date) with **"time.sleep(60)"** in **"test" view** as shown below. Then, **without counting down(decreasing) session expiry time**, [**get_expiry_age()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_age) always returns **the value of [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) or [set_expiry()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.set_expiry)** and [**get_session_cookie_age()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_session_cookie_age) always returns **the value of [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age)** and [**get_expiry_date()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.get_expiry_date) returns **the session expiry date from the current date** as shown below:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
import time

def test(request):
    print(request.session.get_expiry_age())         # 1209600
    print(request.session.get_session_cookie_age()) # 1209600
    print(request.session.get_expiry_date())        # 2022-08-19 22:19:05.376943+00:00
    
    time.sleep(60)

    print(request.session.get_expiry_age())         # 1209600
    print(request.session.get_session_cookie_age()) # 1209600
    print(request.session.get_expiry_date())        # 2022-08-19 22:20:05.392306+00:00
    
    return render(request, 'test/index.html')
```

Finally, I couldn't find the way to get **how much session expiry time is left**.